# Select multiple rows with Eureka framework

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I didn't find in the documentation how to add ability to select multiple rows (see the attached screenshot). I know how to do it with ordinary `UITableView`, but when I use Eureka and call `tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)` nothing happens. Is there any way to implement this with Eureka?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a `MultipleSelectorRow`, for example:

```
<<< MultipleSelectorRow<Emoji>() {
        $0.title = "MultipleSelectorRow"
        $0.options = [, , , , , ]
        $0.value = []
        }
        .onPresent { from, to in
            to.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: from, action: #selector(YourViewController.multipleSelectorDone(_:)))
    }
```

Use it to present a `to` view controller with multiple choices.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need a little different behaviour,  go to iMessage and click edit button in nav bar and you will see edit mode for messages where you can select multiple rows and apply an action (delete, read, ...). This can be easily implemented with ordinary UITableView  - `tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)`, but when I use it with Eureka nothing happens.